# Magento Favorited Product Events

Tags: product, event-observer, review

I'm working on an extension where I want to do something programmatically whenever a user favorites a product in a Magento store.  However — core Magento doesn't the concept of a favorite event,  users usually use a free or commercial extension to achieve this sort of functionality, and every extension will implement this in a different.

Has anyone compiled a list of these sort of events?

Since my guess to the above is no — if you're using an extension like this, which event(s) would you hook into to track a user who marks a products as a favorite?

I know I could download all 6000+ Magento connect extensions and parse these for canidate events, but that leaves out commercial extensions like the [Amasty](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/favorite-products-by-amasty.html) extension.

Comment: Alan, sorry I think I mis-read your question. I am sure you already have the links I supplied in my answer :(

Comment: @brentwpeterson Enthusiasm is not a crime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard directly from the [Amasty](http://amasty.com/) folks, and their favorite extension has an `amlist/item` model that's created whenever you "fav" a product.  This model has no `_eventPrefix` set, but you can use the standard model saving events, and then identify the `data_object` in the observer by its resource name (`amlist/item`) or class name (`Amasty_List_Model_Item`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Events on the Magento WIKI

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events. It is a bit old (2013)

This is a good one from Nick Jones (Meanbee)

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Comment: Yes sorry, I realized that right after I posted my response.